# How does つった translate to cat with stiff legs in: 足がつった猫?

Tags: translation

I saw this line as a caption under a cat YouTube: 足がつった猫
Google translate comes back with : cat with stiff legs.
足が = legs
猫 = cat
But つった, I found on this website is a slangy contaction of つって past tense.
But isn't that "saying"?
I cannot seem to discover how the tsutta makes his legs stiff

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

つった is past tense of つる - there are several verbs pronounced つる, but they all have the same inflection. As far as I can tell using Jisho, the relevant word is 攣る "to cramp; to be cramped; to contract", normally written in kana (that is, after all, a very complex kanji). A [web search](https://duckduckgo.com/?t=ffsb&q=%E8%B6%B3%E3%81%8C%E3%81%A4%E3%81%A3%E3%81%9F&iax=images&ia=images) implies that 足がつった is a common collocation (especially if we look at image results): "[my] leg has cramped". Thus 足がつった猫 is a cat described by 足がつった, i.e. a cat for which its leg is (or legs are) cramped, i.e. a cat with stiff legs.